# Accessing an oracle database file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Without installing microsoft office access an mdb file can be accessed through
microsoft office access database engine.

How can i access a database file in oracle  Without installing Oracle database ?

Comment: Short answer: you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access Oracle database files without the software.  An Oracle database is comprised of several to many files.  The only "engine" that exists that can read these files sensibly is the Oracle database software.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access Oracle datafiles with any hex viewer you like.

Point is, you will have a hard time finding the information in there. Tables are placed in tablespaces and tablespaces are often divided over multiple datafiles, making it hard to access the data in the datafiles without knowing the formats.

Not easy but technically possible.